# Error: failed to find element matching selector for <img data-src="url>

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Running on Puppeteer, all updated.

The intended process is to go to website, where url is url/{search item} and run through the list of search names. Then for each search item --> search page, get name, price and image url for each listing. Now theres error it cannot find selector. Appreciate any help on this, many thanks!

**Layout of the data of the website is as follows:**

```
<div class="items-box-content">
   <section class="items-box">
      <a href="https://listingurl">
         <figure class="items-box-photo">
            <img data-src="https://imageurl.jpg" class=" lazyloaded" src="https://imageurl.jpg">
         </figure>
         <div class="items-box-main">
            <h3 class="items-box-name"> listing name </h3>

            <div class="items-box-figure">
               <div class="items-price font-4"> $29.95 </div> // item's price
            </h3>
         </div>
```

**And what i have now is (which throws the error):**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const searches = ["a", "b", "c"]; //appended to url
(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
   let results =[];
   for (const search of searches) {
         try {
            page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(`https://weburl/?keyword=${search}`);
            await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('div[class*="items-box"]').scrollIntoView();});
            let elements = await page.$$('div[class*="items-box"]');
            for (let element of elements) {
               let listImg = await element.$eval(('img[class="items-box-photo]'), img => img.getAttribute('src'));
               let listTitle = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-main"] > h[class="items-box-name"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
               let listPrice = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-figure"] > d[class="items-price"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
               let listUrl = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-content"] > a[class*="items-box"]'), node => node.getAttribute('href'));

               results.push({ 
                  listImg, 
                  listTitle, 
                  listPrice, 
                  listUrl 
               })
               return results;
            }
         } finally {
            await page.close
         }
   }
})();
```

**The error thrown is**

> (node:5168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to
>   find element matching selector "img[class="items-box-photo]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right there in the error message (`Error: failed to find element matching selector ...`).

The selectors are wrong in the following lines:

```js
let listImg = await element.$eval(('img[class="items-box-photo]'), img => img.getAttribute('src'));
let listTitle = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-main"] > h[class="items-box-name"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
let listPrice = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-figure"] > d[class="items-price"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
let listUrl = await element.$eval(('d[class="items-box-content"] > a[class*="items-box"]'), node => node.getAttribute('href'));
```

According to the HTML code you have given, these should be:

```js
let listImg = await element.$eval('img.lazyloaded', img => img.getAttribute('src'));
let listTitle = await element.$eval('h3.items-box-name', node => node.innerText.trim());
let listPrice = await element.$eval('div.items-price', node => node.innerText.trim());
let listUrl = await element.$eval('div.items-box-content a', node => node.getAttribute('href'));
```

Note, that instead of using `[class=...]` the proper way to query a class is by using the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors): `.`

Comment: for the last one on a href, does it allow for nesting? In this case its div > section > a href.

Comment: On my side, working well `node.getAttribute('href')`

Comment: @Thinkerer Sure, the selector I used last means `a` inside of `div` with class `items-box-content`. You don't need to specify the exact hierarchy when using a selector (but of course you can). Is the code not working?

Comment: I did some simple debug, the selector works fine. I put "debugger;" before "return results" and it shows the correct data for the first listing. Thing is if i run it without debugger, it stops at the first page. No data or errors show up in console. Its supposed to loop through list of search keywords. Then for each keyword, open a page(keyword appended to url) and copy all listings data. Then close and open a new page with another keyword from the list. Pages are opened one by one and not concurrently.

Comment: @Thinkerer Just saw, that you are having a `return` statement in your loop. So after the first iteration the outer function will return and stop. You probably want to move the `return` out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I realized the class changes for different search thats why it works only on first try, but not for later pages. Class=" lazyloaded" or "lazyloaded addedstring" and no space before. I tried *= or ^=" lazyloaded-" but so far not working.

Answer (score 2):

I updated your code with my test/debug.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const searches = ["a"];

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    function delay(timeout) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
        });
    }

    let results = [];

    for (const search of searches) {

        try {
            page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(`https:url/`);

            await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('section[class*="items-box"]').scrollIntoView(); });

            let elements = await page.$$('section[class*="items-box"]');
            console.log(elements.length)
            console.log('wait 6  seconds')
            await delay(6000);

            for (let element of elements) {
                // await delay(6000);

                let listImg = await element.$eval(('img'), img => img.getAttribute('src'));
                let listTitle = await element.$eval(('h3[class="items-box-name font-2"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
                let listPrice = await element.$eval(('div[class="items-box-price font-5"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
                let listUrl = await element.$eval(('div[class="items-box-content clearfix"] a'), node => node.getAttribute('href'));

                results.push({
                    listImg,
                    listTitle,
                    listPrice,
                    listUrl
                });
            }

            debugger;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            //await page.close
            await browser.close
        }
    }
    console.log(results)
    return results;
})();
```

---

**Updated content:**
1. `return result` in `for` loop

```
for(){
   return result;
}
```

=>

```
for(){

}
return result;
```

2. Updated `querySelector`

```
section[class*="items-box"]

img  // There is only one img tags in "element"

h3[class="items-box-name font-2"]  // removed outer 'element'

div[class="items-box-figure"] > div[class="items-price font-4"]

div[class="items-box-price font-5  // updated class name? on my side 

items-box-price

div[class="items-box-content clearfix"] a
```

3. Updated sleep duration 6 Seconds, this is relative network speed(web load duration).
4. `try` `catch` `finally`
   `catch` help you to process next step although crash in one step.

Comment: the line with a href seems to meet the same error, think others are good!

Comment: got this error

(node:6297) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector "div[class="items-box-content"] a"

Comment: Please provide your online weburl, for testing on my side.

Comment: if the HTML is `<div class="items-box-content>` ?, why not `<div class="items-box-content">`?, missing `"`

Comment: Sorry your right. Its <div class="items-box-content">

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Both you and Thomas were right. Since my question was targeted at the selector, i marked his as the correct answer. However would like to thank you for correcting my return and loops thereafter, thanks!