# QuerySelector failed to execute on Element or failed to find matching selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, puppeteer

Im trying to obtain the url of each image in 'figure class > img src'. The webpage contains a list of listings, and each listing has an image.

Problem is the image url class switches between 'class=" lazyloaded"' (*Note space in front of name) and 'class=" is-higher-height lazyloaded"'.

Im thinking of a query along lines of either 'lazyloaded' or 'is-higher-height.lazyloaded'. Nothings works.

Strangely, i tested on a sandbox and it found both items. Link below.

http://pagedemos.com/awr78g4nfehh/3

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

**html structure**

```html
<div class="items-box-content">

   <!-- each section represents a single listing --> 
   <section class="items-box">
      <a href="http:url">

         <figure class="items-box-photo">
            <img data-src="imageurl.jpg" class=" lazyloaded" src="imageurl.jpg">

            <!-- sometimes class=" is-higher-height lazyloaded" -->
         </figure>

      </a>
   </section>

   <!--  many other listings --> 
   <section></section>...

</div>
```

**Main Puppeteer lines**

```js
await page.evaluate(() => { 
  document.querySelector('section[class*="items-box"]');
});

let elements = await page.$$('section[class*="items-box"]');

let listImg    = await element.$eval('img.lazyloaded', img => img.getAttribute('src'));
```

**Tried below for $eval, none works**

```js
//CSS versions
img.lazyloaded //captures 1 listing on debugger;
.lazyloaded                 
is-higher-height.lazyloaded //doesnt capture even 1
.is-higher-height.lazyloaded //doesnt capture even 1
img.lazyloaded.is-higher-height.lazyloaded //multiple classes

//XPath versions
'img[class*="lazyloaded"]'   // includes name 
'img.[class$="lazyloaded"]'  // ends with name 
'img.[class^="lazyloaded"]'  // starts with name 
'//img[class^="lazyloaded"]' //not valid selector
```

Comment: How about `.items-box img`?

Comment: you don't actually use `querySelector` afaict. it is the library's own implementation.

Comment: I think it should be `const srcs = await page.$$eval('.items-box img', img => img.src);` (or just `const imgs = await page.$$eval('.items-box img');` to get all image elements)

Comment: This is my query wrt the full code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887523.  Now error is `results` (an array) is undefined. The error is from `console.log(results)`

Comment: One issue with that code is that you're returning `results` from the `async` in the first iteration of the element loop. And the selectors are way too long and complicated. For instance to get the h3s, all you need is `.items-box h3`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG where should the results be? My error is still there even if i put the `return results` and `console.log` outside of the `for (const search of searches) {` and `try`